# Programing: open 2 popup windows with one click

Tags: java, selenium, popup

is it possible in java or other programing language to open 2 popup windows with one click and one of them to be closed automatically after a certain time?
  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes in thing in the programing can be done

i show the 2 popup menu and you can close one of them after time by using timer or thread and you can change their size by using size method

i am not going to write all code because you ask if you can open 2 popup windows with one click or not 
i iust open the 2  popup windows with one click

```
package experiments;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CreateDialogFromOptionPane {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final JFrame parent = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton();

    button.setText("Click me to show dialog!");
    parent.add(button);
    parent.pack();
    parent.setVisible(true);

    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           new JFrame().setVisible(true);
            new JFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply MoHammed!